# Pointer to an array has it's elements freed once outside scope

Tags: c++, pointers, static, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to read from a binary file, and then convert the binary information from a `char[]` pointer to an `int[]` pointer.

I was wondering, is there something similar to `static int var[]`, but for dynamically allocated arrays?

I am trying to find a way to tell C++ to not free up the memory after exiting the function.

```
imagein.open(loc, ios::binary);
//Creates a pointer to a list of chars with a length of 8, which is just enough for 2 ints
char* timechar = new char[8];

//Reads 8 bytes of data from the file
imagein.read(timechar, 8);

//Creates an int pointer with enough room for 2 vars
int* ints = new int[2];

//Tells C that everything within timechar is now an int, and copies the contents to the ints pointer
ints = (int*)timechar;

//gets the width, and height of the image from the 1st 2 bytes
width = ints[0];
height = ints[1];

//Creates the size var
size = width * height;

//sets the ammout of ints to read to the width * height
times = size;

//creates a pointer to a list of chars so that we can read the data from the file
char* chars = new char[times * 4];

//Reads the rest of the file into chars
imagein.read(chars,times*4);


//reinitilizes buffer to be the correct size to the compiler
int* temp= new int[size+2];

//shifts the pointer to the buffer over twice
++temp;
++temp;


//takes everything from chars and tells C that all the bits within the chars var are copied over as int's
temp = (int*)chars;

//Shifts the buffer pointer back to where it should be
--temp;
--temp;

//sets the 1st, and 2nd buffer vars to the width, and height of the given image
temp[0] = width;
temp[1] = height;

//increases size to the correct size of the array buffer
size += 2;
```

I want to get the `temp[]` of ints to persist after exiting the function.

I am new to C++, and I'm not sure of other ways to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `temp = (int*)chars;` probably doesn't do what you think it does: it overwrites the `temp` pointer that you allocated three lines prior.

Comment: *//Tells C that everything within timechar is now an int, and copies the contents to the ints pointer* That isn't what that expression does. It overwrites the pointer `ints` (leaking the previous array) and pretends `timechar` is an array of `int` (which is isn't). To copy the values you should use `memcpy`.

Comment: *"I am trying to find a way to tell C++ to not free up the memory after exiting the function."* By using `new` this is already what you are doing. Your use of `new` makes it seem like you may be more familiar with object oriented languages like Java or C#. Unlike those languages, in C++ `new` is not the only way to to create an object and in modern C++ it is almost always discouraged A simple declaration like `int ints[2];` creates an array tied to the local scope. If you need dynamic allocation consider using `std::vector` or `std::make_unique` instead.

Comment: How does memcpy work? Does it copy the items from timechar, and save the data to a new location?

Comment: @Rlewerenz You can see here : [std::memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy). Strictly speaking, it is a fix for that specific expression. But overall you should change your approach and just use `std::vector`.

Comment: I tried using std::vectors, and they wouldn't let me reassign the types without changing the bits of data.

Comment: I'm trying to write some data into a file, and them view the data later, but I don't want to a .txt file extension. So, I'm trying to use ofstream(std::ios::binary) to view the binary information stored within the file. Then I'm trying to read the data into a private variable called buffer. When I write to a binary file with int's they come out with different values than what I wrote. So, I cast the array of ints to an array of chars, and then write the char information to the file. Then I undo this same process to get the data I put in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** This is most likely not what the OP needs, but it is what they asked, so I'll keep this answer around instead of deleting it in case anyone else lands here.

> I am trying to find a way to tell C++ to not free up the memory after exiting the function.

The normal reason people want this is in to recycle the dynamically allocated memory across multiple invocations of the function. It "sometimes" has interesting performance benefits, at the cost of preventing the function from being used in multiple threads concurrently.

If that's not what you are attempting to do, then stop reading. Otherwise...

If you want to recycle temporary dynamic storage this way, then a static local variable will get you what you want.

Here's what it would look like using a `std::vector<>`, which you really should instead of raw array pointers.

```
void someFunction(std::size_t size) {
  static vector<int> temp;

  // ...
  if(temp.size() < size+2) {
    temp.resize(size+2);
  }
}
```

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning that `static int* = new int[42];`  kind of works as well (even though it wouldnt pass a code review) as OP is speficially asking for it